# vue.js select a random option from array as default

Tags: arrays, random, vue.js

I try to create a little tool for learning vue.js which should return the time it takes to go somewhere: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Sepp/pen/zZYNoP)

It works more or less for now but I would like to add a random value from each array on page load. How would I have to do this?

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="locationApp" v-model="selectedLocation">
        <option v-for="entry in locList" v-bind:value="entry.distance">{{ entry.name }}</option>
 </select>
```

-

```
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#App',
  data: {
    locList: [
      { name: 'New York', distance: '100' },
      { name: 'Barcelona', distance: '500'  },
      { name: 'Hawaii', distance: '600' }
    ],
    vehicleList: [
      { name: 'Car', speed: '100' },
      { name: 'Bicycle', speed: '25' },
      { name: 'A pair of Shoes', speed: '5' }
    ],
    selectedVehicle: '0', // here I'd like to add a random speed
    selectedLocation: '0',// here I'd like to add a random distance
  },
  computed: {
    calculateThis: function () {
      return Math.abs(this.selectedLocation / this.selectedVehicle)
    }
  }
});
```

I read about the ready tag:

```
    ready: function() {
     //I guess I have to grab the select here somehow ??
   },
```

Comment: Could you clarify "But I had no luck"?  Did you get an error?  Do you see any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWxoGY). As you use vue.js 2.0 use the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) method in combination with [this.$tick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

Since you used v-model and added a value to the select options you have to assign the "random" value to the v-model variable.

as seen here

```
mounted: function() {
   this.$nextTick(function() {
      var randomVehicle = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.vehicleList.length);
      var randomLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.locList.length);
      this.selectedVehicle = this.vehicleList[randomVehicle].speed;
      this.selectedLocation = this.locList[randomLocation].distance;
   });  
},
```

The math random calculation does nothing more then provide a range for the random selection. I just used this....length for the maximum and 0 for the minimum.